# Sorting a table that pulls from a database in a custom wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, plugins

I am building a Wordpress plugin and trying to sort my database tables by last name, first name, address etc when someone clicks on the title of the column.

I am unsure why but when I click a column title link, I get the following message:
"Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." My filename is lead_db.php.
I have also tried to enter /admin.php?page=lead-db-editor-handler which is what the url reads on the page when I open it in the backend; this brings me to a 404 when I click to sort. I have been at this for hours now and can not figure it out or find the answer online. Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <th data-sort-initial='descending'><a>ID</a></th>
  <th><a href="lead_db.php?sort=time">Registered Date</a></th>
  <th><a href="lead_db.php?sort=last_name">Last Name</a>, 
      <a href="lead_db.php?sort=first_name">First Name</a></th>
  <th><a href="lead_db.php?sort=address_1">Address 1</a></th>     
 </tr>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_client_info";

if ($_REQUEST['sort'] == 'id')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY id";
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['sort'] == 'time')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY time";
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['sort'] == 'last_name')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY last_name";
}
elseif($_REQUEST['sort'] == 'first_name')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY first_name";
}
?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error())    
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['time'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['last_name'], ", ",$row['first_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_1'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}
mysql_close();
?>

</table>
```

Comment: As an aside, is pagination involved? And don't use deprecated APIs

Comment: in this example there is no pagination. Thanks for pointing out the dep. API. $__GET should be $_REQUEST.  I'll update it now.

Comment: If you just want to order a result, then there's no need to carry the overhead of hitting the database each time. You can just re-sort the array, or, better, just use a bit of script/css to rearrange. Here's one example that googling found, but there must be lots of others... http://mbraak.github.io/simple-data-grid/#demo

Comment: Thanks Strawberry! That sounds like a much better idea than what I was doing. Looking into doing a script/css now. Will post back with updated code as I am not too familiar with this type of method but is clearly a much better way.

Comment: I have been looking more into Jquery methods and stumbled across this gem!
http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html
This is def the way to go and should be fairly easy to setup. Will post back with my results and modified code :D